# How can I include the request.User details in Django's traceback email for a production site

Tags: django, debugging, production-environment

I would like to include the contents of request.user in the context details emailed to the site admins when an error occurs, as well as the traceback and request.GET/POST/COOKIES/META

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because process_exception middleware gets passed the request object, you can add whatever info you like to request.META

```
class ErrorMiddleware(object):
    """
    Alter HttpRequest objects on Error
    """

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        """
        Add user details.
        """
        request.META['USER'] = request.user.username
```

Comment: Tack on a `.username`, because with a recent Django you get a lazy object that doesn't pretty-print well.

Answer (score 2):

Make a middleware that has a `process_exception` method.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception

```
import sys
import traceback
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

class ProcessExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if not settings.DEBUG:
            msg = '\n\n'.join([request.user, request.GET, request.POST, \
                request.COOKIES, request.META, traceback.format_exc(*sys.exc_info())])

            mail_admins("Error!", msg)
```

I hope that gives you some ideas!

Comment: That was massively helpful, thanks :) Unfortunately you can't stop BaseHandler continuing to process the Error and thus sending you an email unless you return an HTTPResponse... And getting two emails for each error is overkill

Comment: Ohh, ouch. The docs even suggest making admins blank to stop the auto emails so you're right, that doesn't work. Nice solution though! That's a hell of a lot cleaner.