# Include django logged user in django Traceback error

Tags: django

What is the easist way to include username, first and last name and e-amil in django Traceback error.

I know that the way is [create a custom error report](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/):

1. Create a new class that innherit from django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter
2. Set DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER

But, what method a should overwrite to receive traceback with also this information?

I would like that my treceback look likes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr...o/core/handlers/base.py", line 89, in get_response
   response = middleware_method(request)

 File "/.../g...ap/utils/middleware.py", line 23,...
   if elapsedTime.min > 15:

TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to int

Logged user information:
User:    pepito
name:    Pepito Grillo
e-mail:  grillo@peppeto.com
```

Comment: Here's a cleaner way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4946443/565259

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it using Custom Middleware. I'm not sure this is the best answer, but it is how I solved it for my project.

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'utilities.custom_middleware.CustomMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

utilities/custom_middleware.py:

```
from utilities.request import AddRequestDetails

class CustomMiddleware(object):
"""
    Adds user details to request context during request processing, so that they
    show up in the error emails. Add to settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and keep it
    outermost(i.e. on top if possible). This allows it to catch exceptions in
    other middlewares as well.
"""

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        """
        Process the request to add some variables to it.
        """

        # Add other details about the user to the META CGI variables.
        try:
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                AddRequestDetails(request)
                request.META['AUTH_VIEW_ARGS'] = str(view_args)
                request.META['AUTH_VIEW_CALL'] = str(view_func)
                request.META['AUTH_VIEW_KWARGS'] = str(view_kwargs)
        except:
            pass
```

utilities/request.py:

```
def AddRequestDetails(request):
"""
    Adds details about the user to the request, so any traceback will include the 
    details. Good for troubleshooting; this will be included in the email sent to admins 
    on error. 
"""
if request.user.is_anonymous():
    request.META['AUTH_NAME'] = "Anonymous User"
    request.META['AUTH_USER'] = "Anonymous User"
    request.META['AUTH_USER_EMAIL'] = ""
    request.META['AUTH_USER_ID'] = 0
    request.META['AUTH_USER_IS_ACTIVE'] = False
    request.META['AUTH_USER_IS_SUPERUSER'] = False
    request.META['AUTH_USER_IS_STAFF'] = False
    request.META['AUTH_USER_LAST_LOGIN'] = ""
else:
    request.META['AUTH_NAME'] = str(request.user.first_name) + " " + str(request.user.last_name)
    request.META['AUTH_USER'] = str(request.user.username)
    request.META['AUTH_USER_EMAIL'] = str(request.user.email)
    request.META['AUTH_USER_ID'] = str(request.user.id)
    request.META['AUTH_USER_IS_ACTIVE'] = str(request.user.is_active)
    request.META['AUTH_USER_IS_SUPERUSER'] = str(request.user.is_superuser)
    request.META['AUTH_USER_IS_STAFF'] = str(request.user.is_staff)
    request.META['AUTH_USER_LAST_LOGIN'] = str(request.user.last_login)
```

Comment: I will test. I will come back with news.

Comment: I'm rereading your post. I'm looking for a way to add meta information only in exceptions, not for all requests. To avoid overhead. What do you think about this?

Comment: In the CustomMiddleware class, you could override process_exception, and use the same code as above. Just change `def process_view(...` to `def process_exception(...`. I haven't tested this, but I think it should work. More on the custom middleware here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: I just noticed that the syntax for process_view is different than process_exception. They have different parameters passed into them. From the aforementioned django website, the process_exception should be written: `def process_exception(self, request, exception)`. Sorry about that.

Comment: It doesn't work, although in django 1.5, see my solution below

Answer (score 8):

My trivial solution (works in django 1.5)

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'utilities.custom_middleware.UserTracebackMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

custom_middleware.py:

```
class UserTracebackMiddleware(object):
    """
    Adds user to request context during request processing, so that they
    show up in the error emails.
    """
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request.META['AUTH_USER'] = unicode(request.user.username)
        else:
            request.META['AUTH_USER'] = "Anonymous User"
```

hope it helps