# Post json to django but get 500 error

Tags: python, json, django

I'm writing an app to post json to Django, but get a 500 error in terminal like

[27/Jan/2015 20:50:38] "POST /datasave/ds/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10414

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
$('#upload').click(function() {
    var json_obj = {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        game_id1: '123',
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token}}'
    };

    $.post("http://192.168.0.109:8000/datasave/ds/", JSON.stringify(json_obj), 
        function(data) {
          alert("OK");
        }, 
        "json");
})
})
```

And Django views code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def ds(request):
    dicty = {}
    if request.is_ajax:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            req = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
            obj, created = 
                Gamer.objects.update_or_create(
                username=req.get(u'username', None), 
                password=req.get(u'password', None), 
                game_id1=req.get(u'game_id1', None))
            print obj, created
    dicty['username'] = req.get(u'username', None)
    dicty['password'] = req.get(u'password', None)
    dicty['create_at'] = str(timezone.now())
    return JsonResponse(dicty)
```

Comment: You may debug your view to isolate and fix the mistake. Apache / console log data can helps. A simple way to isolate issue: comment code lines and fill with fake data until view works fine, then uncomment line by line.

Comment: You are probably getting a `KeyError` when accessing `req['game_id1']`, since by the looks of it that key doesn't exist.

Comment: It's a KeyError like mattm and Simon say. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting a 500 Internal server error one could assume that there is an issue in your view handler code. It's hard to say what's causing it really, so you should try to figure why it's happening. From looking at your code I can see two things that might cause this error.

First you are using `dict` as a variable name, which is probably a bad idea since `dict` is a built-in type in python.

The other possible cause could be the way your are accessing the `req` dict. You are accessing the keys `username`, `password` and `game_id1`. If any of these should be missing in the dict it will throw a `KeyError` exception. I like to access dicts using `req.get('username', None)` instead (replace `None` with another default value if you prefer. Another way to tackle that issue would be try/catch exception handling.

Also, depending on your Gamer model, trying to create a using an existing username (assuming you have `unique=True`) would probably throw an exception as well, so you should handle that as well (I think [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) could be handy here).

Generally when dealing with problems of this kind, use the inspector in your browser. It lets you see all the data sent and received during the request, which means (if you're running django in `DEBUG` mode) you'll also get to see the default stack trace page in the inspector. It should hold some valuable indication to what's causing the issue. Another option would be to [write a small middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4945858/222245) or [enable extended error logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/) to log errors to `strout`/`stderr`.